# Review of Proof of DeMorgan’s law for sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I would like the following proof to be reviewed for correctness and clarity of the argument as well as simplicity and wording, in one sentence: Where can I do better?

**Proof that $(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c$.**

*We will prove the above in two parts, showing that each of the sets $(A \cup B)^c$ and $A^c \cap B^c$ is subset of the other one.*

**Part 1:** Proof that $(A \cup B)^c \subseteq A^c \cap B^c$:

1: Let $x \in (A \cup B)^c$. Then $x \notin A \cup B$.

2: Because $ A \cup B = \{y | y \in A \vee y \in B\}$, it must be that $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$.

3: As $x \notin A$, it must be that $x \in A^c$, and similarly $x \notin B$ means that $x \in B^c$, we can note that $x \in A^c \cap B^c$.

4: Thus $\forall x(x \in (A \cup B)^c \implies x \in A^c \cap B^c)$, which is $(A \cup B)^c \subseteq A^c \cap B^c$.

**Part 2:** Proof that $A^c \cap B^c \subseteq (A \cup B)^c$:

1: Let $x \in A^c \cap B^c$, but for contradiction assume $x \notin (A \cup B)^c$.

2: $A \cup B = \{y | y \in A$ or $y \in B\}$, so $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.

3: If $x \in A$, then $x \notin A^c$ and also $x \notin A^c \cap B^c$, similarly if $x \in B$, then $x \notin B^c$ and also $x \notin A^c \cap B^c$.

4: As this means that $x \notin A^c \cap B^c$ we have a contradiction to our initial statement that $x \in A^c \cap  B^c$. Therefore the assumption that $x \notin (A \cup B)^c$ must not be the case, meaning that $x \in (A \cup B)^c$.

5: Hence $\forall x(x \in A^c \cap B^c \implies x \in (A \cup B)^c)$, that is $A^c \cap B^c \subseteq (A \cup B)^c.$

Comment: Don't see any issues with this proof. Your reasoning is correct and clear.

Comment: Yeah it all looks good. Just a formatting tip for you though, it seems in step 4 of part 1 and step 5 of part 2, you've used \rightarrow ($\rightarrow$), when you should've used \Rightarrow ($\Rightarrow$ ).

Comment: @SeraPhim: I will edit the arrow, but logically would that not be \implies? (Edit: I see someone already edited it accordingly)

Comment: Is there anything that from a wording perspective could be improved at all, or is this how it all should be worded?

Comment: Part 1 Point 3, you can just add "Hence $(A \cup B)^c \subseteq A^c \cap B^c$", and eliminate point 4. Otherwise it can be seen as redundant. Part 2 Point 2, the wording can be more similar to Part 1 Point 2, that's my preference. Finally Part 2 Point 2, I would just say "Hence $ A^c \cap B^c \subseteq (A \cup B)^c$" it is clear enough without the whole $\forall$ part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the proof is correct. But since you are also interested in simplicity, I think it is possible to make it a little less verbose.

For example, part 1 (2) you write

$$ A \cup B = \{y | y \in A \vee y \in B\}$$

I believe that it is safe to assume that anyone who reads your proof knows what $A \cup B$ means. So more concisely, you could just write "Since $x \not \in A \cup B$, we have $x \not \in A$ and $x \not \in B$".

In the part 1 (step 4) you write

$$\forall x(x \in (A \cup B)^c \implies x \in A^c \cap B^c)$$

As my current understanding stands, it is not preferred to use first order logic in proofs. Plain english would be a better choice.

So in the end, you first part could be reduced to:

"Take $x \in (A \cup B)^c$. Then we have $x \not \in A \cup B$, which means that $x \not \in A$ and $x \not \in B$, but then $x \in A^{c}$ and $x \in B^{c}$, and thus $x \in A^{c} \cap B^{c}$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we have $(A \cup B)^c \subseteq A^c \cap B^c$ ."

Now to the second part:

1. As in the part 1, I believe stating the definition of $A \cup B$ is not necessary.
2. And again, if your audience is familiar with a proof by contradiction (most likely they are), in the step 4 you just write "but then $x \not \in A^{c} \cap B^{c}$, a contradiction. Hence if $x \in A^{c} \cap B^{c}$, we must have $x \in (A \cup B)^c$."
3. And yet again, like in the part 1, I think using plain English instead of the first order logic is a better choice. So instead in the step 5, you could just write "$x$ was arbitrary, hence $A^{c} \cap B^{c} \subseteq (A \cup B)^c$."

So the second part might look like:

"By contradiction. Suppose for some $x$, we have $x \in A^c \cap B^c$ but $x \not \in (A \cup B)^c$. Then $x \in A \cup B$, which means that either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. If $x \in A$, we have $x \not \in A^{c}$. If $x \in B$, then $x \not \in B^{c}$. In both cases, we have $x \not \in A^{c} \cap B^{c}$, a contradiction. Hence if $x \in A^{c} \cap B^{c}$, we must have $x \in (A \cup B)^c$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $A^{c} \cap B^{c} \subseteq (A \cup B)^c$."

Comment: Your suggestions make sense to me. I will rewrite this proof out for myself accordingly. I likely should not edit it here because that would render your answer not useful. As you write that English is preferred to first order logic, is there somewhere a commonly accepted standard of how to "write math"?

Comment: @AxelJanssen If you write something like a PhD thesis, I think there must be some standard. (Although if you are looking for details, I’d strongly advise you to ask someone else, as I have never had experience in writing any math papers). The reason I said why it is “preferred to use plain English over first order logic” is because: 1. I was told so by numerous users on MSE (when I was asking to review my proofs) 2. So far, most of the proofs that I’ve seen do not use first order logic, which makes me believe that, indeed, plain English is more preferable. (and IMHO, it is more readable)

Comment: @AxelJanssen But regardless, what matters the most is clarity. If people can understand what you wrote, it doesn’t make a huge difference whether you used English or first order logic. Your proof is perfectly fine, so don’t worry too much about the style.

Comment: I had been asking for feedback on structure, clarity and simplicity because I feel that sometimes the lack of these elements can obfuscate a lack of understanding. The better someone understands, the more simply they should be able to articulate themselves. I will follow your feedback reg. first order logic! TY

Comment: @AxelJanssen As a side note: you seem to be interested in logic and proofs, so I'd recommend you to have a look at "How to Prove It: A Structured Approach" by Daniel J. Velleman. It does a *very* good job at explaining how mathematical proofs should be approached. (at least this is the first book I've picked up when I started learning about writing more or less "formal" proofs) Good luck!